# React router v4 nesting

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My routes config looks like this:

```
[
    {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        component: Dashboard
    },
    {
        path: '/stories/:storyId',
        component: Story,
    },
    {
        component: Dashboard,
        status: 404
    }
]
```

Now inside of the Story component I want to render a gallery and every photo needs to have its own url. Did something like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Redirect from={match.url} to={`${match.url}/1`} />
    <Route path={`${match.url}/:photoId`} render={this.renderGallery } />
</Switch>
```

Unfortunately it goes into an infinite loop cause match.url never changes after the redirect.

Can somebody help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `from` on `<Redirect>` matches loosely by default. As you have it, it will match anything that starts with whatever's in match.url, which includes your ${match.url}/1 path.

Inside of Switch, it's actually reading the props of its children directly and doesn't distinguish the type of component. So, [you can use `exact` and `strict`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js#L42) like you can on a Route.

Therefore, this should work for you:

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect exact from={match.url} to={`${match.url}/1`} />
  <Route path={`${match.url}/:photoId`} render={this.renderGallery } />
</Switch>
```